# SSIS get emails from database and send individual emails

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008, ssis

I need to schedule a task that runs monthly that will query sql server, get a list of emails, and send individual emails to everybody in the list.

I'm assuming I need to use SSIS to schedule the monthly task, but I'm not sure if I should be doing all of the work in sql server and use a stored procedure and the Database Mail, or if I should use SSIS to call a .Net executable that does all of the work?

Any suggestions on how to do this?

Comment: What is the nature of the email? If it is report or report-like ssrs may be a better tool, with built in scheduling and email delivery. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms160334.aspx

Comment: SSIS knows nothing of scheduling-that responsibility is the domain of SQL Agent. If you want or need the OOB functionality of SSIS (logging, configuration, etc) use that. Otherwise, I'd invoke sp_send_dbmail as steps within a SQL Agent Job (less maintenance). If you need a more .NET feeling solution, I'd go PowerShell. DBAs tend to be ok with a script they could crack open (and not read). Give them a black box EXE to run on the server and they laugh you out of the building.

Answer (score 1):

Personally I have done the same types of things in SQL Server.  You can setup SQL Mail and write a stored procedure that will pull the email addresses.  Then you can simply use `msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail` and provide a `profile` name, a list of `recipients`, the `subject`, an `attachment`, etc all as options.

Then you can use the jobs section in sql server to run this sproc monthly, weekly, hourly, etc.

Comment: would it be better to do it all in sql server, or create a console app in .Net that does all the work, and then just schedule the exe to run monthly?

Comment: @user1202606 - thats all up to you and your dba's or development team.  Its the same sort of thing, you will still need to call a stored procedure to get the data (the emails), if you can do it all on the sql server side as a job wrap it up in that.  If not go ahead and create a .net c# or vb.net app that processes it and schedule it.  Same thing really.

Answer (score 0):

SQL Authority has a good step by step on how to do this from within the database without using SSIS. 
http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2008/08/23/sql-server-2008-configure-database-mail-send-email-from-sql-database/

After setting it up you can use SQL Agent to schedule a proc that processes and sends the email.